# Why inner structure having a member of enclosing struct type works when declared inside member function

Tags: c++, inner-classes

I have the following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/xWbb4ha4z), that compiles, but when I move the struct from member fn to the struct scope it fails to compile.

I understand that compiler sometimes can not work with incomplete types, but I wonder why moving it inside function fixes the problem.

I see no difference in terms of information compiler has about parent class regardless where `IncResult` is placed.

```
#include <fmt/printf.h>


struct Num {
    // IncResult moved here does not work:
   //  error: field has incomplete type 'Num'
    auto inc() {
        struct IncResult {
          bool _event;
          Num result;
        };   
        return IncResult{(val+1)%2==0,Num{val+1}};
    }

    int val = 0;
};

int main() {
    Num num{10};
    auto [eleven_even, eleven] = num.inc();
    fmt::print("{}, {}\n", eleven_even ? "even " : "odd  ", eleven.val);
    auto [twelve_even, twelve] = eleven.inc();
    fmt::print("{}, {}\n", twelve_even ? "even " : "odd  ", twelve.val);
}
```

Comment: The language needs to accept the structure/class inside inline functions, otherwise inline member functions just wouldn't make sense. How it's implemented practically, or how it's specified in the C++ specification I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

How can the compiler do it:

The struct Num inside a function is just a local variable in that function. It doesn’t exist until you call the function.

Outside the function, you are saying that the struct Num contains a struct Num, which contains a struct Num, which contains a struct Num and so on.

Comment: Neither of those points are applicable to the OP's question. They're asking why type `Num` is incomplete when used in a nested class definition, but not when used in a member function definition. This isn't about local variables versus member variables.

Comment: _"The struct Num inside a function is just a local variable in that function."_  Are you confusing `struct X {};` with `struct {} X;`? `Num` is a type, not a variable.

Comment: _"Outside the function, you are saying that the struct Num contains a struct Num, which contains a struct Num"_ Again, type not variable. In their example, `Num` doesn't contain a `Num`, it just attempts to define a nested class that contains a `Num`. There's no member in `Num` of the nested class' type.